# Database - Should total price be stored in a column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have `orders` and `items` table. Here's the association

```
# order.rb
has_many :items

# item.rb
belongs_to :order
```

What I'm wondering is: Should I keep the total price in the order table? The total price is summed from each item.

I need to generate **Chart** and the only data needed is the total price.

My app is still on local development so I haven't had any performance issue. But I'm guessing it will start having an impact after there are few hundreds of orders.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you keep the total price in the orders table as well.

One common thing about shops is that prices change. And when they change they create a huge mess (in both accounting and stats) unless you keep them somewhere other than the product itself.

There is no need to worry about performance for that thing.

Comment: I'd use an after_save callback on the order so that each time it is updated the total price is validated or updated as required.

Comment: @robin I have separate table called `products` for the base information. Because past order's amount shouldn't change when I increase the price of a product.

Comment: @xlembouras Thanks for the suggestion, I will put total price in table

Comment: @DarcCode Agreed that the item price is "locked" when the order is created. I'm considering the scenario where a user creates a basket, goes away, and comes back and updates/changes the basket. You'll need a methodology for updating the total price in the DB accordingly.

Comment: @RobinFisher For that scenario, I think it's best if you just keep the basket as cookie. But only keep product's ID so the price will be updated.